# Using COUNT (DISTINCT..) when also using INNER JOIN to join 3 tables but Postgres keeps erroring

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, inner-join

I need to use INNER JOINs to get a series of information and then I need to COUNT this info. I need to be able to "View all courses and the instructor taking them, the capacity of the course, and the number of members currently booked on the course."

To get all the info I have done the following query:

```
SELECT
    C.coursename, Instructors.fname, Instructors.lname,C.maxNo, membercourse.memno
FROM Courses AS C
INNER JOIN Instructors ON C.instructorNo = Instructors.instructorNo
INNER JOIN Membercourse ON C.courseID = Membercourse.courseID;
```

but no matter where I put the COUNT it always tells me that whatever is outside the COUNT should be in the GROUP BY

I have worked out how to COUNT/GROUP BY the necessary info e.g.:

```
SELECT courseID, COUNT (DISTINCT MC.memno)
FROM Membercourse AS MC
GROUP BY MC.courseID;
```

but I don't know how to combine the two!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to solve this, such using Window Functions and so on. But you can also achieve it using a simple subquery:

```
SELECT
    C.coursename, 
    Instructors.fname, 
    Instructors.lname, 
    C.maxNo, 
    (SELECT 
        COUNT(*) 
    FROM 
        membercourse 
    WHERE 
        C.courseID = Membercourse.courseID) AS members
FROM 
    Courses AS C
    INNER JOIN Instructors ON C.instructorNo = Instructors.instructorNo;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! that worked perfectly! I'm completely new to SQL so the help was much appreciated!

Comment: Glad to help you @user8992790

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is a subquery.  I'm a SQL-Server guy (not postgresql) but the concept looks to be almost identical after some crash-course postgresql googling.

Anyway, basically, when you write a SELECT statement, you can use a subquery instead of an actual table.  So your SQL would look something like:

```
select count(*)
from
(
    select stuff from table
    inner join someOtherTable
)
```

... hopefully that makes sense.  Instead of trying to write one big query where you're doing both the inner join and count, you're writing two: an inner one that gets your inner-join'ed data, and then an outer one to actually count the rows.

**EDIT: To help explain a bit more on the thought process behind subqueries.**

Subqueries are a way of logically breaking down the steps/processes on the data.  Instead of trying to do everything in one big step, you do it in steps.

In this case, what's step one?  It's to get a combined data source for your combined, inner-join'ed data.

**Step 1: Write the Inner Join query**

```
SELECT
    C.coursename, Instructors.fname, Instructors.lname,C.maxNo, 
membercourse.memno
FROM Courses AS C
INNER JOIN Instructors ON C.instructorNo = Instructors.instructorNo
INNER JOIN Membercourse ON C.courseID = Membercourse.courseID;
```

Okay, now, what next?

Well, let's say we want to get a count of how many entries there are for each 'memno' in that result above.

Instead of trying to figure out how to *modify* that query above, we instead use it as a data source, like it was a table itself.

**Step 2 - Make it A Subquery**

```
select * from
(
    SELECT
        C.coursename, Instructors.fname, Instructors.lname,C.maxNo, 
    membercourse.memno
    FROM Courses AS C
    INNER JOIN Instructors ON C.instructorNo = Instructors.instructorNo
    INNER JOIN Membercourse ON C.courseID = Membercourse.courseID
) mySubQuery
```

**Step 3 - Modify your outer query to get the data you want.**

Well, we wanted to group by 'memno', and get the count, right?  So...

```
select memno, count(*)
from
(
    -- all that same subquery stuff
) mySubQuery
group by memno
```

... make sense?  Once you've got your subquery written out, you don't need to worry about it any more - you just treat it like a table you're working with.

This is actually incredibly important, and makes it much easier to read more intricate queries - especially since you can name your subqueries in a way that explains what the subquery represents data-wise.

Comment: Hi, @Kevin thanks for your answer!
I tried as you suggested above and got the error "subquery in FROM must have an alias"

So I then tried:
SELECT COUNT (*)
FROM
(SELECT C.coursename, Instructors.fname, Instructors.lname,C.maxNo, membercourse.memno
FROM Courses AS C
INNER JOIN Instructors ON C.instructorNo = Instructors.instructorNo
INNER JOIN Membercourse ON C.courseID = Membercourse.courseID
) AS courseID;

but this only gives me the count and I can't group by/separate the results and I don't get any of the information from the INNER JOIN...only:

count
bigint
9

Comment: Again, I'm not a postgresql expert, but in MS-SQL, an error like that means that you have to name the subquery.  Something as simple as:  Select count(*) from (select something from somehwere) as mySubQuery.  Also, I'm going to expand my answer to help explain how to think about subqueries.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the explanation definitely made things a lot clearer!